# Sum rasters with different extent in R

Tags: raster, r, extents

I need to sum several rasters (.tiff) with different extent but the same resolution in R.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you need the minimum or maximum extent as output?

Comment: the maximum @aldo_tapia

Comment: You can use `extend()` with the maximum extent. I'll post an elaborate answer in a few hours

Answer (score 12):

Sample data:

```
r1 = raster(xmn=0,xmx=11,ymn=0,ymx=11,res=1)
r1[]=1:ncell(r1)
r2 = raster(xmn=5,xmx=8,ymn=6,ymx=9,res=1)
r2[]=1:ncell(r2)+5
```

Now two functions, first to get the max extent of a list of rasters:

```
extend_all =
function(rasters){
 extent(Reduce(extend,rasters))
}
```

Then one to sum all rasters padded to a specified extent:

```
sum_all =
function(rasters, extent){
 re = lapply(rasters, function(r){extend(r,extent)})
 Reduce("+", re)
}
```

Then:

```
r_sum = sum_all(list(r1,r2), extend_all(list(r1,r2)))
plot(r_sum)
```

[image]

Note this pads small rasters out with NA values. If you want zeroes instead use

```
sum_all = 
function(rasters, extent){
 re = lapply(rasters, function(r){extend(r, extent, value=0)})
 Reduce("+",re)
}
```

This might be useful if your data is 0/1 counts and you are summing ones in each cell from rasters with varying extents.

Comment: Nice, thanks! In applications where `extend_all()` is too slow (as reported by @kory below), using `function(rasters)  {Reduce(union, sapply(rasters, extent))}` instead should speed things up.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry unable to comment as I don't have a 50 rep yet, but Spacedman's solution for getting the max extent is very slow on large datasets, this is much faster:

```
rasters <- list(ras_01, ras_02, ras_03, ras_04, ras_10, ras_13, ras_19, ras_22)
getMaxExtent <- function(rasters) {
  extents <- sapply(rasters, FUN = function(x) {
    raster::extent(x)
  })
  r <- raster(ext = extents[[1]], nrows = rasters[[1]]@nrows, ncols = rasters[[1]]@ncols)
  max_extent <- sapply(extents, FUN = function(x) {
    r <<- raster::extend(r, x)
  })
  raster::extent(r)
}

getMaxExtent(rasters)
```